# java class similar to Android Bundle class

Tags: java, android

There is an useful class in android (at least for me). The **Bundle class** which allows you to put a kind of pair Key Value. But the value can be a different established classes of objects.

For example:

```
Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
mBundle.putInt("Number One", 1);
mBundle.putBoolean("True", true);
```

There is a **similar class in java**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I know of, but it's fairly easy to reproduce with a `HashMap`:

```
public class Bundle extends HashMap<String,Object>{

   public void putString(String key, String str){
      put(key, str);
   }

   public String getString(String key){
      Object o = get(key);
      if(o!=null && o instanceof String)
         return (String) o;
      return null;
   }

   public void putInteger(String key, int anInt){
      put(key, new Integer(anInt));
   }

   public Integer getInteger(String key){
      Object o = get(key);
      if(o!=null && o instanceof Integer)
         return (Integer) o;
      return null;
   }

   ...

}
```

Comment: You can extend `Map<String, Object>`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Java contains this kind of `Object` by default but you can create one:

```
public class Bundle extends HashMap<String, Object> {

    public void putInt(String key, int value) {
        put(key, value);
    }

    public void putString(String key, String value) {
        put(key, value);
    }

    public Integer getInt(String key) {
        if (containsKey(key) && get(key) instanceof Integer) {
            return (Integer) get(key);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public String getString(String key) {
        if (containsKey(key) && get(key) instanceof String) {
            return (String) get(key);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```